# XML Parsing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml coming from an XMLHttpRequest (for a Firefox extension). In the following code, req is an XMLHttpRequest object. I did `req.overrideMimeType("text/xml");`  after declaring req.

```
var shortURL;  
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);  
xmlDoc.async = false;  
xmlDoc = req.responseXml;  
if (xmlDoc.readyState == 4){  
    shortURL = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[8].text;  
}
```

If I use `req.responseXml` I get an error saying "xmlDoc is not declared" for the line after `xmlDoc = req.responseXml;` If I use `req.responseText`, `xmlDoc.readyState == 4` turns false.

I don't do much of javascript so please tell me if I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: `xmlDoc.readyState` doesn't make sense because `xmlDoc` is an XML *document* not an XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 1):

I generally prefer using `responseText` and then parsing the XML using the browser's built in XML parsing library. After that, I generally convert the resulting XML document tree, or a sub tree, to JSON for easy access in JavaScript.

I wrote a tiny utility library for this here:

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/myearth/lib/xmlutil.js

The usage is pretty simple:

```
var json = xmlNodeToJson(parseXml(req.responseText);
```

Comment: I can get a direct JSON reply from the server. SO I use the JSON format now. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Hai chanux,

May this will help you to know  [basics of xml parser](http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp)

http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript

[AJAX responseXML errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013582/ajax-responsexml-errors)

or try changing

```
shortURL = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[8].Text;
```

to

```
shortURL = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[8].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

or use this function and change it for yours...

```
function parseXML()
    {
        if (xmlDoc.readyState == 4 && xmlDoc.status == 200)
        {
                xmlDoc = xmlDoc.responseXML;
                regions = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("region");
                for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++)
                {
                    if (regions[i].getAttribute("id") == regID)
                    {
                        var browserName = navigator.userAgent;
                        var isIE = browserName.match(/MSIE/);
                        if (isIE)
                        {
                            var hotelprice = regions[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                            var pkgprice = regions[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var hotelprice = regions[i].childNodes[1].textContent;
                            var pkgprice = regions[i].childNodes[3].textContent;
                        }
                        document.getElementById("hotel").innerHTML = "$"+hotelprice;
                        document.getElementById("package").innerHTML = "$"+pkgprice;   
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the DOM? If not, use [E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/e4x). It's as simple as

```
shortURL = new XML(req.responseText).child(8).text();
```

If the response includes an XML declaration (`<?xml version="...">`), use this instead:

```
shortURL = new XML(req.responseText.replace(/^<\?xml\s+version\s*=\s*(["'])[^\1]+\1[^?]*\?>/, "")).child(8).text();
```