# Getting xml tag names in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I had been trying to get the tag name and its value in java script. The xml file which I use looks like below:

```
<root>
    <note>
        <to>Gil</to>
        <from>
            <firstname>john</firstname>
            <lastname>corner</lastname>
        </from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
    </note>
    <note>
        <to>Mary</to>
        <from>
            <firstname>Clara</firstname>
            <lastname>Diana</lastname>
        </from>
        <heading>
            How are you
        </heading>
    </note>
</root>
```

I would like the output to be as below:

```
TageName : root Attribute: 0 Text: null

TageName : note Attribute: 0 Text: null
TageName : to   Attribute: 0 Text: Gil
TageName : from Attribute: 0 Text: null
TageName : firstname Attribute: 0 Text: john
TageName : lastname Attribute: 0 Text: corner
TageName : heading Attribute: 0 Text: Reminder

TageName : note Attribute: 0 Text: null
TageName : to   Attribute: 0 Text: Mary
TageName : from Attribute: 0 Text: null
TageName : firstname Attribute: 0 Text: Clara
TageName : lastname Attribute: 0 Text: Diana
TageName : heading Attribute: 0 Text: How are you
```

Is this possible. If so, please help me...

Comment: Is this a homework question? In any case, please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Google `javascript parse xml`

Comment: See these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972790/xml-parsing-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var xml = '<root><note ><to>Gil</to><from><firstname>john</firstname><lastname>corner</lastname></from><heading>Reminder</heading></note><note><to>Mary</to><from><firstname>Clara</firstname><lastname>Diana</lastname></from><heading>How are you</heading></note></root>';

var node = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml").documentElement;

var nodes = node.querySelectorAll("*");

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var text = null;
    if (nodes[i].childNodes.length == 1 && nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeType == 3) //if nodeType == text node
        text = nodes[i].textContent; //get text of the node
    console.log("TageName : ", nodes[i].tagName, ", Text : ", text);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plowdawg/UNwR2/) that shows the basic use.  And here is the basic code using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(this).find("root").children().each(function()
     {
             alert($(this).get(0).tagName+":"+$(this).text());                                 
       });                                                                                     
 });
```

Modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the response. I had just started to learn xml and java script. Once I'm done with this i will start with Jquery. Anyways..thanks a lot...