# Javascript can't interpret returned xml

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

Seems my javascript isn't picking up on my php sending back an xml document. php code:

```
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

/* append it to the document created */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($domtree->createElement("root"));

foreach (glob('./img/photos/*.*') as $filename) {
    //echo $filename;
    $xmlRoot->appendChild($domtree->createElement("image",$filename));
}

/* get the xml printed */
echo $domtree->saveXML();
```

The output of the code above is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><image>./img/photos/2012-02-26 17.02.12.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-03-09 08.21.48.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-07-21 14.09.39.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-07-25 15.25.17.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-08-04 17.54.38.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-08-04 23.36.30.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-08-06 06.08.43.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-08-07 20.57.34.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-08-09 20.40.11.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-08-25 20.54.05.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-09-07 11.19.50.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2012-09-08 15.53.27.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2013-01-30 19.19.16.jpg</image>
<image>./img/photos/2013-01-31 09.48.39.jpg</image></root>
```

Calling this with AJAX, when I call AJAXRequest.responseXML i get null back.

EDIT: AJAX Request Code:

```
function requestImages()
{
    request=new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "getPhotos.php");
    request.onreadystatechange=showPhotos;
    request.send();
}

function showPhotos()
{
    if ((request.readyState == 4)) {
        doc=request.responseXML; // This returns null
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the AJAX code? Also call it directly an write back what is the output of the php so we can see what Javascript is trying to parse.

Comment: see answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013582/ajax-responsexml-errors)

Comment: Is your PHP Script returning the correct `Content-Type` header? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3272572/156755 for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using any third party library, try this kind of code snippet (modify it according to your requirement)

```
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
```

Note that it is using request.responseText and it will definitely get the returned xml if you will add content type as `header("Content-type: text/xml");` in your header

**UPDATE**

To parse the xml, you can use the below code snippet:

```
function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}

function doNothing() {} //use this for some processing at run time
```

Comment: Any reason not to use jQuery and avoid having to do the browser sniffing yourself? Also, you're not parsing the XML into a usable format, just calling back with a string

Comment: Yeah jQuery is the best to use here.. but I believe @jaysee is not using it so it will add another learning curve right now? And yes xml is being parsed I just suggested the relevant code

Comment: Only reason I'm not using jQuery is that I don't know it. Also, I'd prefer to avoid any platform specific code (ActiveX is windows only, right?)

Comment: OK this works. The first code snippet gives me an XML document I can work with as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the content type in php so AJAX know that is a xml and parse it (remember that this must be done before any `echo`):

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
```

This can also be forced directly in javascript (with `overrideMimeType()`) but is better done in php.